# how to debug the apache output filter

Tags: apache-2.2, debugging

i am working on the output filter but it is behaving very abnormally. i am not gettin the the data from the server in continous chunk. it's like first data from the server then next chunk will be the filtered data then again partial data from the server then again filter partial data. i am not able to understand the behaviour. Thanks in Advance.

Please tell me how to debug the code i have apache 2.2.4( unix)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup up bridages and buckets.

Apache does not promise to send the data single chunks but in buckets - there may be one or many.